# convert ten digit number into date excel

Tags: excel, date

I have a CSV file which contains some dates. These dates are formatted as 10 digit numbers:
I have used the formula `=TEXT(LEFT(A1,5),"dd-mmm-yyyy")` but this returns the wrong date.

Then 10 digit numbers are with corresponding correct date:

```
1410666955 is 14-September 2014
1413514597 is 17-October 2014
1433822231 is 9-June 2015
```

Can anyone help me what formula to use to convert to the proper date?

Thanks to Cha, i've managed to convert the number into a Date.

The number was Unix based and i used the following formula:

=(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)+(9/24)

The 9/24 is because i live in Melbourne Australia

Comment: You have a UNIX timestamp. Read here: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/converting_unix_timestamps/

Comment: It seems that the dates are in HEJRI calendar, right? In that case, excel can not convert directly from Hejri to Gregorian

Comment: @cha you can post that as answer. It does solve the OP's issue. Take note of the GMT though.

Comment: Thank you Cha, that worked great.  I used =(((A1/60)/60)/24)+DATE(1970,1,1)+(9/24)  The +9 is because i'm in Melbourne (aus) and the dates matched

Comment: Actually to get what you want, you'll have to use this: `=TEXT((A1/86400)+25569+(9/24),"dd-mmmm yyy")`

Comment: `>>> import datetime`
`>>> datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(1410666955)`
`datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 13, 22, 55, 55)`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unix date format consists of the number of seconds that have passed since 1-Jan-1970.

Knowing that, it is just a matter of calculating how many days have passed, and then adding those days to 1-Jan-1970.

Here is the formula I used to convert those seconds into proper Dates:

```
=FLOOR(A1/60/60/24,1) + DATE(1970,1,1)
```

Note that I use `FLOOR` to get rid of hours/minutes/seconds in that day. If you need more precission, don't use `FLOOR`

Here is the output I got:
[image]